# Supervisord: Setting priorities to stop last, start last

Tags: supervisord

I have 3 programs in a group.

```
[program:p2]
command=...

[program:p1]
command=...

[program:p3]
command=...

[group:myprograms]
programs=p1,p2,p3
```

I want the `p3` program to always stop last *and* start last.

My understanding of the `priority` configuration option is that it allows me to indicate that a certain program would start first and shut down last (lower number) or start last and shut down first (higher number).

How can I be sure that `p3` will always stop last and start last?